How to bundle boot loader with a boot loader?
My goal here is to get the linux kernel to run on a very old machine that I doubt supports UEFI booting. This old machine doesn't have any operating system so I can't install grub or any other boot loader. And I've seen these other Linux distributions come bundled with boot loaders like Grub. Googling this question results in nothing. I've configured my kernel with the menuconfig but I can also go back and change settings if needed.
TL:DR: How can I bundle a boot loader like Grub with my Linux kernel installation + how can I boot into this kernel + bootloader on an external device (other computer)?

"a very old machine" - If you want useful advice, then provide accurate information instead of ambiguity.
